# Classification of kinship system by languages

Tags: reference-request, linguistic-typology, resource-request, comparative-linguistics, kinship-terms

I'm looking for a way to compare "closeness" of languages based on their kinship systems.
The only thing I found is [this classification](https://www.umanitoba.ca/faculties/arts/anthropology/tutor/kinterms/termsys.html), which classifies kin systems to: Eskimo, Hawaiian, etc.
*There is no list of languages for each class though, which makes it very difficult.

However, **is there a dataset/place where given a language you have the kin system class?**

For some languages I'm googeling it and I can find it easily, but for many NOT.

**Is there another way to compare languages based on kin terms?**

Thanks for any help in the matter!

Comment: the wikipedia pages for the various kinship system classes (linked from the page below) give a very much incomplete list of languages using each system. Unfortunately WALS does not seem to have a chapter on kinship system, which would be where I'd normally go for this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinship_terminology#Six_basic_patterns_of_kinship

Comment: @Tristan Thanks for the answer! I saw that WALS does not have a chapter on Kinship. I'm not a linguist myself. I'm wondering: does it make any sense that there are no lists of languages in each kin system? no database to compare languages solely on there kin terms/system?

Comment: it's a little surprising to me, but not massively so. I think it's probably because kinship often falls in the crack between linguistics and anthropology, so people making linguistics databases will often overlook it, as will those making anthropological ones